# How do you apply style rule in Safari Web Inspector?

Tags: safari, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Developer Tools allows you to apply a style rule in the Styles pane.  I haven't found a way to do this in Safari (Style Rules pane).  Any one know if it is possible?

Also, does Safari have rulers like Chrome does?

Comment: its a little quirky as i am used to chrome and FF dev tools myself but i just put up a writeup of how to do it

Answer (score 9):

**Safari 8.0.8 on OS X**

1. Right-click any element and select *Inspect Element* from the pop-up menu
2. Ensure *Styles* and *Rules* are selected on the right hand side of the inspector
3. You can then either add individual rules by clicking *+ New Rule*, or simply click and start typing rules where *Click to Edit* appears (refer to image below)
4. Enter your new rules and these will be applied to the element being "inspected" in the browser window.

[image: Safari Inspector - apply styles rules]

As for a ruler? Well, I haven't found one, but the *Inspect* button will give you the dimensions of elements when hovered in the browser window.

[image: Safari Web Inspector Inspect button]

[image: Safari element inspection]

Comment: The new rule *must* be applicable to the currently selected element, or else it will immediately disappear. For example, if you have a `<p>` selected, you can't make a `span {}` rule.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the DevTools-like panel (CMD + OPT + C)
2. Click on the Elements tab
3. If it's not open yet, click on "Show the details sidebar" on the right (CMD + OPT + 0)

OR

1. Right-click element and select "Inspect Element"
2. If it's not open yet, click on "Show the details sidebar" on the right 
   (CMD + OPT + 0)

Answer (score 1):

YES this is absolutely possible - and here is how:

---

[image: Safari 6.0.1 style editor]

**Safari 6.x.x**

(Safari 6.0.1 Solution Confirmed on Mac OsX)

*for the newest version of Safari 6.0+ Apple has taken the luxury of removing those gui elements.  the feature is still available however just a little more tucked away.* to add your styles in safari 6 you need to follow said steps:

**the STEPS:**

1. first choose the `{}` brackets icon in the right sidebar
2. From the DOM model in the center white area of the web inspector- Click to select the HTML element you wish to view styles of. ( they will display in the right style sidebar )
3. On the right style sidebar: double click the closing brace on the existing style for the selector you wish to edit.

   ```
    OR
   ```

   Double click the open area beneath the "Style Attribute" drop down in that same sidebar to add your own styles to that particular element

---

**Safari 5.x.x and previous** (5.x.x Confirmed Win 7 & Mac OS X)

assuming you have enabled the inspector in the settings advanced menu you can begin right clicking and inspecting elements...

from that point select an element in the DOM on the left from the html markup.  now on the right sidebar make sure the "Style" menu is expanded.

once here you have two options:

[image: inspector style menu right sidebar]

there should be a blank "element.style" selector available for every DOM element you can select from the left. these are intended for your customization.  you can double click here to be given the option to add styles to that selector.

[image: the option gear]

you can also click on the gear at the top right corner of the styles menu in that right side bar and choose the last option "New Style Rule"  this will allow you to define your own selector independent of the DOM element you have chosen on the left

[you can find the full apple documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/1Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I'm not seeing these options.  My window looks like the one from the Apple link.  Yours is completely different.  I'm running Safari 6.0.4.

Comment: I am going to cross check my version of safari 6 and see if I can't hash this out. But I was speaking about the style panel in my answer not inline

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying now.  It just isn't that obvious in the answer.  First click some element in the left pane.  In the Styles pane, click any closing brace and that will add a entry for the new rule.

Comment: One more thing from the OP, does Safari have rulers?